# Check the Object Size

Tags: modeling

I'm working to print a model designed by Blender Software, but I have a challenge to know the object size before printing that, because I have to insert the material based on the model size .

example:
the below left object is the design and the right is UV which I would like to know the size of it .

[image]

So how can I know the model size if become as flat ?

Comment: What do you mean with: So how can I know the model size if become as flat? There are no metric units in the UV Editor. Do you want the Volume, Bounding Box Dimensions or some Edge Loop Length?

Answer (score 1):

is not clear imho: do you wish to know the *volume* of the mesh, or the *surface area*, or the UVmap *width/height*?

I guess you perhaps need help from the (default bundled) 3d print addon:

[image]

this is what you get if you're using the default unit: "blender unit".

But you can change it to a custom unit, like this:

[image]

and get the area or volume calculated in the same unit (depending on your model size).

If you can't see this addon on the toolbox's side, you just need to enable it in user preferences.